# What customizations are available for helm's matching?

Tags: helm, helm-projectile

I've been looking for a list of options that control how `helm` matches and sorts the "source" list.

In today's example, I was using `helm-projectile-find-file` looking for `gif.rb` and Helm takes the `.` the same as a space.  Rather I needed to type `qif\.rb` to get Helm to narrow its focus like I wanted it.  Is there an option that controls this?

A few days ago, I was working on my Emacs init files which I've put into Org mode files.  In that case, when I typed `foo` using `helm-find-files`, the resulting list would include `foo.org`, `foo.el`, and `foo.elc`.  I'd like to never see the `foo.elc` file and I'd prefer to have the `foo.org` be before the `foo.el` file.  Indeed, if both of them exist, utopia would be for `foo.el` to be in different "source".

Last, if there is an exact match in the list, I'd like it to be picked first.  Very often I don't use Helm like I should (pilot error) and I do `C-x foodog` and whack the return and expect `foodog` to have been selected but very often it isn't.  It is Helm's best guess of what it thought I wanted.  Helm's history plays a part in this as well.  What is odd in I see in other cases, Helm seems to do this.

Comment: I know nothing about `helm` but it sounds as if it is using regexps for matching, where the period `.` matches *any* single character. That's why you have to escape the period: the escaped period matches `.` only,

Comment: @NickD I'm sure it is using regular expressions too but it is also doing a lot of other stuff.  For example you can have spaces and if I type `foo dog` it will match `foo.*dog` as well as `dog.*foo` and even `foo.*foo`, etc.  The space is special so there might be an option to make `.` and `*` not act as part of a regular expression.

Comment: You're asking multiple questions. To answer you second questions, try setting `helm-ff-skip-boring-files` to t.